# Parse from String and convert to float, integer (Raku)

Tags: raku

FAQ: In Raku, how do I parse a [String](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str) and get a [Number](https://docs.raku.org/type/Num) ? For example:

```
xxx("42");  # 42 (Int)
xxx("0x42");  # 66 (Int)
xxx("42.123456789123456789");  # 42.123456789123456789 (Rat)
xxx("42.4e2");  # 4240 (Rat)
xxx("42.4e-2");  # 0.424 (Rat)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the [prefix +](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#prefix_+):

```
say +"42";  # 42 (Int)
say +"0x42";  # 66 (Int)
say +"42.123456789123456789";  # 42.123456789123456789 (Rat)
say +"42.4e2";  # 4240 (Rat)
say +"42.4e-2";  # 0.424 (Rat)
```

- Info

**[val](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/val)** a [Str](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str) [routine](https://docs.raku.org/type/Routine) is doing exactely what you (I) want.

Beware that it is returning [Allomorph object](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#Allomorph). Use [unival](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/unival) or just [+ prefix](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_+) to convert it to [Number](https://docs.raku.org/type/Num)

- Links:
- [Learning Raku](https://www.learningraku.com/2016/11/26/quick-tip-11-number-strings-and-numberstring-allomorphs/): Number, Strings, and NumberString Allomorphs
- Same question in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906), [Perl](https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=210343)
- [Roseta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Raku): Determine if a string is numeric

Edited thanks to @Holli comment

Comment: Normally you don't need `val`. You can just rely on automatic type conversion or just use the `+`. `say (+'0x42').WHAT; #Int`.

Answer (score 5):

```
my regex number {
    \S+                     #grab chars 
    <?{ defined +"$/" }>    #assertion that coerces via '+' to Real
}

#strip factor [leading] e.g. 9/5 * Kelvin
if ( $defn-str ~~ s/( <number>? ) \s* \*? \s* ( .* )/$1/ ) {
    my $factor = $0;
    #...
}
```

Comment: I use this combination of ‘+’ and look ahead assertion to test a sub string for Real.

Comment: Nice watchguard to check : the `val` answer do not check and must be CATCH.

Comment: Referenced, thank you! https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708355/227738